# Differentiating 8 variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I was differentiating an equation and it led me to this:

$$ \frac{PA}{1+AF}-\frac{QB}{1-BF}-\frac{XC}{1+C-CF}+\frac{YD}{1-D+DF}=0$$
I need to find F, where P+Q=1 and X+Y=1.

I tried expanding everything, but it becomes crazy long. I was wondering if there are any shorter methods. Or is it not solvable?

Comment: Hi all! thanks for the extremely quick comments! I have decided to show the full equation, instead of some poorly done substitution which I did to simplify the equation.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

First, you only have six variables, because of the two relations. You want to maximize $PA+(1-P)B+XC+(1-X)D$  Then you can take partial derivatives with respect to each and set to zero, so $\frac \partial{\partial P}(PA+(1-P)B+XC+(1-X)D)=A-B=0$ and so on for each other variable.  Note that there is no maximum-you can set $A=B$ and $C=D$, then you rexpression is $B+D$, which grows without limit.

Comment: Thanks!!! But really sorry!! I modified the question. Thought my substitution was really poorly done. SOrry once more!

Comment: The same idea applies.  Use the relations to eliminate two variables, say $Q,Y$, then take all the partials and set to zero.